# How to get the xhr.response.statuscode

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to know how to use XMLHttpRequest to get response from ws.

I tried this code to post my vale:

```
  private prepareSave(): any {
    const endpoint = (Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.createContrat));
    let XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const input: FormData = new FormData();
    input.append('contratedate', this.addContratForm.get('contratedate').value);
    input.append('contratdesc', this.addContratForm.get('contratdesc').value);
    input.append('unit_price', this.addContratForm.get('unit_price').value);
    input.append('files', this.addContratForm.get('files').value);
    input.append('token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
   XHR.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
       alert('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
   });

     XHR.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
       alert('Oups! Something went wrong.');
     });

    XHR.open('POST', endpoint);

    console.log(input)
    XHR.send(input)
    console.log(XHR) // show me XMLHttpRequest.
  }
```

My response is:

```
   {
    "StatusCode":0,
    "StatusMessage":"OK",
    "StatusDescription":
    [
    {
    "error_no":0,
    "error_msg":"",
    "sqlerrorno":0,
    "sqlerror":"",
    "lastid":"11E84DE6579F6599A4FBFA163EBBBC1D"}
    ]
    }
```

I tried something like this code, but no function:

```
if (XHR.response.StatusCode === 0) {
          Materialize.toast('Contrat update successfully', 4000);
          this.router.navigate(['/main/contrats']);
         return true;
       }
```

Please, can you suggest any solution?
Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Also, why are you not using Angulars built-in HttpClient class?

Comment: Work correctly this code, Only I want to display in background StatusMessage. How to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
private prepareSave(): any {
    const endpoint = (Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.createContrat));
    let XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const input: FormData = new FormData();
    input.append('contratedate', this.addContratForm.get('contratedate').value);
    input.append('contratdesc', this.addContratForm.get('contratdesc').value);
    input.append('unit_price', this.addContratForm.get('unit_price').value);
    input.append('files', this.addContratForm.get('files').value);
    input.append('token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
   XHR.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
       alert('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
   });

     XHR.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
       alert('Oups! Something went wrong.');
     });

    XHR.open('POST', endpoint);

    console.log(input)
    XHR.send(input)
    XHR.onload = function () {
      let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
      if (jsonResponse.StatusCode === 0) {
        Materialize.toast('Contrat saved successfully', 4000);
        window.location.href = '/main/contrats';
        return true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
XHR.StatusCode instead of XHR.response.StatusCode ? cause as i can see from your logged object there is no response attribute...